# How to keep dtypes when reading a parquet file(read_parquet()) in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, parquet

Code:

```
In [31]: df = pd.DataFrame({"a": [[{"b": 1}], [{"b": np.nan}]]})

In [32]: df
Out[32]:
              a
0    [{'b': 1}]
1  [{'b': nan}]

In [33]: df.dtypes
Out[33]:
a    object
dtype: object

In [34]: df.to_parquet("a.parquet")

In [35]: pd.read_parquet("a.parquet")
Out[35]:
               a
0   [{'b': 1.0}]
1  [{'b': None}]
```

As you can see here, `[{'b': 1}]` becomes `[{'b': 1.0}]`.

How can I keep dtypes even in reading the parquet file?

Comment: Are you sure the  dtypes have changed or is it merely a display issue?

Comment: I think dtypes has been changed because when I `pd.read_parquet("a.parquet")["a"].values.tolist()` -->  `[array([{'b': 1.0}], dtype=object), array([{'b': None}], dtype=object)]` the values are `array` type...  which was orignally not..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to use `pyarrow.parquet.read_table` and `pyarrow.Table.to_pandas` with `integer_object_nulls`  (see the [doc](https://arrow.apache.org/docs/python/generated/pyarrow.Table.html#pyarrow.Table.to_pandas))

```
import pyarrow.parquet as pq

pq.read_table("a.parquet").to_pandas(integer_object_nulls=True)
```

|  | a |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | [{'b': 1}] |
| 1 | [{'b': None}] |

On the other hand, it looks like [`pandas.read_parquet`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_parquet.html) with `use_nullable_dtypes` doesn't work.

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({"a": [[{"b": 1}], [{"b": None}]]})

df.to_parquet("a.parquet")
pd.read_parquet("a.parquet", use_nullable_dtypes=True)
```

|  | a |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | [{'b': 1.0}] |
| 1 | [{'b': None}] |

Comment: It still `{'b': 1.0}` instead of `{'b': 1}` ...

Comment: oops my bad. Just edited the answer